# Alternate for ServiceHost in .Net 5

Tags: migrate, .net-5, servicehost

Currently i am migrating my class library project from .net framework 4.6.1 to .Net 5.
where i am using ServiceHost class to host wcf server.
As The WCF Server functionality will not be supported in .Net. what is the work around for this.

```
public static ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(object singleObject, string baseAddress, Type serviceContract, string endPoint, bool isNetBinding)
    {
        if (InstEnvironment.Instance.LogVerbose)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("ServiceUtility.CreateServiceHost() entered...");
            sb.AppendFormat("\t\t\t  baseAddress: {0}", baseAddress);
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("\t\t\t  endPoint: {0}", endPoint);
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("\t\t\t  serviceContract: {0}", serviceContract.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("\t\t\t  isNetBinding: {0}", isNetBinding.ToString());
            LogUtility.LogMessage(sb.ToString(), LogUtility.Log.MessageType.Verbose);
            sb.Length = 0;
        }

        Uri baseAddressUri = new Uri(baseAddress);
        ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(singleObject, new Uri[] { baseAddressUri });

        // Service Behavior
        ServiceDebugBehavior debugBehavior = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        if (debugBehavior == null)
        {
            debugBehavior = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(debugBehavior);
        }
        debugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

        ServiceMetadataBehavior metaDataBehavior = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        if (metaDataBehavior == null)
        {
            metaDataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(metaDataBehavior);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CoreWCF` repo is the server-side port of `WCF` for `.NET Core` and they have the sample server
https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/tree/master/src/Samples/NetCoreServer

Some reasons behind it:

> This isn't a straight port of WCF Server/ServiceHost. To do a straight
> port would have made cross platform support almost impossible. It
> would have meant more code in the repo, meaning more code which needs
> to be maintained and a higher chance of bugs on non-windows platforms.

https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/issues/227#issuecomment-700295498